# How to access variables declared in a custom Vue js plugin inside Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created a custom Vue js plugin to store global variables like so:

Constants.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {

    install(Vue){

        Vue.Constants = {
            VERSION: '1.0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import Constants from './plugins/Constants'

Vue.use(Constants);

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

But when I tried accessing this constant in my App.vue  it says undefined:

```
{{ Vue.Constants.VERSION }}  // Not working
{{ Constants.VERSION }} // Not working
```

I even tried importing Vue in App.vue like so:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

// Rest of the code

<script>
```

Please suggest, There are article on how to create and install custom plugin but I couldn't find how to access it in Vue components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tweak your code a little:

**Constants.js** file:

```
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$constants = () => {
      return {
        VERSION: '1.0.1'
      };
    };
  }
}
```

You have to add it to `Vue.prototype` not just `Vue`. Also, it's a convention to prefix the plugin with **$** and lower-case it (`$constants` and not `Constants`).

This returns a function - so you have to call it like a function:

**App.js** or any other SFC:

```
{{ $constants().VERSION }} // expected: 1.0.1
```

---

#### SUGGESTION

If you just updated your plugin a bit, then it could really be a "constant-store":

**Constants.js** file:

```
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$constants = function(...args) {
      const constants = [
        [
          "VERSION",
          "1.0.1"
        ],
        [
          "RELEASE",
          "05/08/20"
        ],
        [
          "RELEASED BY",
          "I've released it."
        ]
      ]
      return args.length
        ? Object.fromEntries(constants.filter(([key]) => args.includes(key)))
        : Object.fromEntries(constants);
    };
  }
}
```

If you try it out, then it's quite versatile:

**App.js** or any other SFC:

```
{{ $constants() }} // expected: { "VERSION": "1.0.1", "RELEASE": "05/08/20", "RELEASED BY": "I've released it." }
{{ $constants("VERSION", "RELEASE") }} // expected: { "VERSION": "1.0.1", "RELEASE": "05/08/20" }
{{ $constants("VERSION") }} // expected: { "VERSION": "1.0.1" }
```